# How do you obtaining a count of predictors after backward stepwise selection?

Tags: r, regression

Let's say that I have a full model, with many many predictors, how can I obtain a count of the number of predictors left over after a stepwise selection has been done? In this example it is a backward stepwise reductio See sample code below: n

```
library(ISLR)
set.seed(1)
mtcars$vs <-as.factor(mtcars$vs)
mtcars$gear <-as.factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$cyl <-as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
complex_model <- glm(mpg ~ (cyl+hp+vs+gear+wt+drat+qsec)^2, data=mtcars)
step_reduction <-step(complex_model,direction="backward",test="F")
step_reduction
```

Comment: Do you count the interactions as well `length(coef(step_reduction))-1`

Comment: Yes. The problem is that in other areas where I've tried this, the number of predictors left over in the model does not appear to be consistent with what I'm observing the step function to do. As I'm watching the output of the step function, I'm watching it eliminate only 1 or 2 predictors before stopping, but then when I check length, as you had suggested, it seems to say that I had eliminated around 60...Perhaps I'm reading the output of the step function incorrectly?